# Is Inn(N(H)) subgroup of Aut(H) if H is subgroup of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If H is subgroup of G. Then can we say that **Inn(N(H))** is subgroup of **Aut (H)**. Where **Inn(N(H))** is group of inner automorphisms of Normalizer of H. 
Here, I proved that if  f_g is function(g belongs to N(H) and f_g(x)=gxg^-1 for all x belonging to N(H)) belonging to Inn(N(H)) then f_g is also element of Aut(H).
But, problem is here we have to restrict domain of f_g from N(H) to H.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that elements of $\mathop{\rm Inn}(N(H))$ are functions whose domain and codomain are $N(H)$ while elements of $\mathop{\rm Aut}(H)$ are functions whose domain and codomain are $H$. Therefore, $\mathop{\rm Inn}(N(H))$ cannot be a subgroup of $\mathop{\rm Aut}(H)$ (unless $N(H)=H$).

It's true, as you imply, that there is a natural map from $\mathop{\rm Inn}(N(H))$ to $\mathop{\rm Aut}(H)$, namely take a function $f_g$ as you described and restrict it to a function on $H$. Note however that this map from $\mathop{\rm Inn}(N(H))$ to $\mathop{\rm Aut}(H)$ need not be injective—in other words, there can be two distinct elements of $\mathop{\rm Inn}(N(H))$ that restrict to the same automorphism of $H$. (For example, consider the trivial case $H=\{e\}$.) Therefore even with this natural map in mind, we can't naturally consider $\mathop{\rm Inn}(N(H))$ to be a subgroup of $\mathop{\rm Aut}(H)$ in general.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I actually faced this question while understanding proof of **N/C** theorem. In that theorem we say that N(H)/C(H) is isomorphic to some subgroup of Aut(H). I understood full proof. But, I want to know which subgroup of Aut(H) we will get? In proof we are taking elements from Inn(N(H)) and restricting their domain to H. So, that it will be element of Aut(H). So, this subgroup will be all elements of Inn(N(H)) deleting repeatation , But I want to know how this subgroup looks like??

Comment: Might be worth posting a new question to that effect!